# How to remove gap between column ordering in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created 3 cards with 2 widgets in the sidebar. To make it responsive I have used bootstrap 4 column ordering.

Now the issue I'm facing is if I have 2 columns in one row and the right column is larger than the left column it shows space in-between card 1 and card 2 because card 1 is smaller than widget 1 or 2.

Can anyone help me how can I remove this gap?

Codeply link for better responsive viewing:

https://www.codeply.com/go/8cNp9dUyE5

My code preview is below:

```css
.left-panel {
  background: gray;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.right-sidebar, .bg-pink {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 bg-pink">
            <div class="row d-md-block">
                <div class="left-panel col-md-8  order-0 float-left">
                    <div class="box1 mt-2"><p>Box 1</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-sidebar col-md-4 order-3 float-left">Widget 1</div>
                <div class="right-sidebar col-md-4 order-1 float-left">
                    <p>Widget 2</p><p>Continue Widget 2</p><p>Widget 2 About to End</p><p>Widget 2 Ends</p>

                
                </div>
                <div class="left-panel col-md-8 order-3 float-left">
                    <div class="box2 mt-2 ">Box 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="left-panel col-md-8 order-5 float-left">
                    <div class="box3 mt-2">Box 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Real-life example: https://prnt.sc/ouscan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSPjy.png)

Answer (score 2):

It's not totally clear to me what you are trying to do here, but simplifying your classes will remove the gap:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left-panel col-md-8">
            <div class="box1 mt-2"><p>Box 1</p></div>
            <div class="box2 mt-2">Box 2</div>
            <div class="box3 mt-2">Box 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-sidebar col-md-4">
            <p>Widget 1</p><p>Widget 2</p><p>Continue Widget 2</p><p>Widget 2 About to End</p><p>Widget 2 Ends</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can re-introduce the ordering classes if needed, but this will at least remove the gap.  Depending on what the contents of the boxes and the widgets are, you may want to include rows within the two columns also.

**Edit**

If you were to create a re-usable component that represents your right side bar this would be a bit cleaner, but here is an option:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left-panel col-md-8">
            <div class="box1 mt-2"><p>Box 1</p></div>
            <div class="right-sidebar d-md-none">
                <p>Widget 1</p><p>Widget 2</p><p>Continue Widget 2</p><p>Widget 2 About to End</p><p>Widget 2 Ends</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box2 mt-2">Box 2</div>
            <div class="box3 mt-2">Box 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-sidebar d-sm-none d-md-block col-md-4">
            <p>Widget 1</p><p>Widget 2</p><p>Continue Widget 2</p><p>Widget 2 About to End</p><p>Widget 2 Ends</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @schuno, can you try and reorder for me one thing only? I want "widget 1" to appear between box 1 and 2 in a mobile device.

Comment: @RamboRon see above for an option using display

Comment: but this has duplicated the code. The reason for using Bootstrap ordering is that I don't want to duplicate the code.

Comment: I'm not sure you can accomplish this with the bootstrap grid.  As I mentioned in my answer, if you created a re-usable component for the "right-sidebar" I don't think it would be too messy to include that component twice.

Comment: I can't do that and that's why I am using Bootstrap ordering instead of reusable component.

Comment: Well I suppose if you have that constraint then you could also try to use negative margins for the bottom 2 divs ("box 2" and "box 3").  I was able to eliminate the gap by doing this.  Of course you would only want these margins to appear on the larger screen size, using a breakpoint.  Not the best solution, but it would work..

Comment: Yes. I have already done that. But I was not thinking it as a solution. I was looking for a proper solution. Also, can you tell me what do I have to do if I have to stick the bottom box? I tried the bootstrap sticky-top class and it didn't work. It was working previously :S

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you might want to simplify your html and wrap your elements sort of like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            BOXES GO HERE
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            SIDEBAR GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The floats are battling what the bootstrap grid does automatically.

---

**NEW** This might be more what you are looking for using `row-eq-height`:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height" style="background-color: blue;">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="box1 mt-2">
        <p>Box 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Widget 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-eq-height" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="box1 mt-2">
        <p>Box 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Widget 2</p>
      <p>Continue Widget 2</p>
      <p>Widget 2 About to End</p>
      <p>Widget 2 Ends</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-eq-height" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="box1 mt-2">
        <p>Box 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Widget 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How will I do ordering then in smaller devices if I follow your pattern? According to your suggestion if I have boxes in one column and sidebar in another then how will I enter sidebar 1 card between box 1 and box 2 in mobile device?

Comment: Tried again, you can match the height of the rows

Comment: you could also have your right sidebar in there twice, and show/hide them with breakpoints (hide the one between box 1 & 2 when not in mobile, show on mobile).  Probably not the best solution but it would work

Comment: Matching height will again give a blank space. Here's a preview: https://prnt.sc/ouszk1 which is looking ugly design.

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to prevent that. You may need to rethink the layout and web design if that's the case.

Comment: This is my desired result: https://prnt.sc/out0v5 How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use the first example and keep all of your boxes in one column and all widgets in a sidebar column

Comment: Okay, but when it comes to reordering how do I put widget 1 between card 1 and 2 in smaller devices? I know for the fact that I can put the whole sidebar on the top or bottom of the cards but not something what I require.